# change/create hotkeys for vertex\edge\face select

Tags: customization, shortcut

I would like to create or change the hotkeys for the vertex select, edge select, and face select options. I know that they already have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>3</kbd>, but I don't like using them. They are a pain to use. I would like to change it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>3</kbd>. I know you can use the python script to do a lot of these things but I don't really know how to set that up.

Is there a way to make these changes?

Answer (score 3):

Can use the window manager context setting operators. The property that needs changing is

```
scene.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode
```

which is a 3 member collection.  All modes  `(True, True, True)`, just verts `(True, False, False)`.  To set verts alonr `mesh_select_mode[0] = True`.

To set them individually,  set vert select mode on. Leaves faces and edge mode as is.

```
bpy.ops.wm.context_set_boolean(
        data_path="scene.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[0]", 
        value=True)
```

to toggle

```
bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(
        data_path="scene.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[0]")
```

To set the mode to vert only

```
bpy.ops.wm.context_set_value(
        data_path="scene.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode", 
        value="(True, False, False)")
```

or `mesh.select_mode` with no extend selection and vert type.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, 
        use_expand=False, 
        type='VERT')
```

Ok that looks good, add to 3Dview, mesh shortcuts.

[image]
*Setup with `wm.context_set_value`*

now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will set to vert mode.