# Calling Vertex, Edge and Faces with 1 shortcut key

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I saw another user who wanted to map 1, 2, 3 to select vertex, edges, faces respectively. We assume we are doing this on EDIT MODE:
[change/create hotkeys for vertex\edge\face select](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92573/change-create-hotkeys-for-vertex-edge-face-select)

I would like to ask if there´s a way to keymap scene.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode **directly** to a key while IN OBJECT mode, so in turn the shortcut will switch to EDIT mode **without doing** "ctrl+tab"?

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-mesh-selection-mode

Comment: I believe I've read that you can assign Python scripts to keyboard shortcuts inside keymaps, but I don't actually know how to do it

Comment: I mentioned *switching to edit mode - face select* on 1 keystroke. Doing it in 2 steps is what the other realated post answers. I'd like to know if it is possible to do it on 1 keystroke. or at least how could the .py code on a custom button would do the call. Thanks.